# eNets Payment Gateway Integration for an ASP .NET website

Tags: asp.net, payment-gateway

I have an asp.net application which needs to be integrated with eNets Payment Gateway for payment through online. How can I do this? Can anybody help me with some reference links or guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its provides a .NET and Java Integration guide. I assume that you are going to use credit card payment method of that - http://www.nets.com.sg/merchants/products/credit-cards. Here in slider there is a link for enet integration guide.

You can find the whole PDF for ASP.NET and Microsoft.NET Integration from below.
http://www.nets.com.sg/images/pdf/umapi_net_merchant_v2.1.pdf

Comment: Hi Jalpesh, this guide seems to have moved out. Do you have any idea on some sample or new guide?